# iPhone: AVCaptureSession capture output crashing (AVCaptureVideoDataOutput)

Tags: iphone, image-processing, camera, video-capture, avfoundation

I'm capturing video and converting it to a CGImage to do processing on it. It will work for a ~10 seconds, get memory warning and then crash (usually it says data formatters were temporarily unavailable). Can someone help me solve the problem?

```
- (void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {

// CONVERT CMSAMPLEBUFFER INTO A CGIMAGE
CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);


uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);


CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
CGImageRef cgimage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);
UIImage *sourceImage= [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimage scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored];
CGImageRelease(cgimage);
CGContextRelease(newContext);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);


// ***
// Adding code after this point to do image transformation usually causes it to crash
UIImage *rot = [self scaleAndRotateImage:sourceImage];
self.detectImage = rot;



}
```

Code to transform the image....

```
- (UIImage*)scaleAndRotateImage:(UIImage *)image{
    int kMaxResolution = 320; // Or whatever

    CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    if (width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution) {
        CGFloat ratio = width/height;
        if (ratio > 1) {
            bounds.size.width = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio;
        }
        else {
            bounds.size.height = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio;
        }
    }

    CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
    CGFloat boundHeight;
    UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
    switch(orient) {

        case UIImageOrientationUp: //EXIF = 1
            transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored: //EXIF = 2
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDown: //EXIF = 3
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored: //EXIF = 4
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored: //EXIF = 5
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft: //EXIF = 6
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: //EXIF = 7
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight: //EXIF = 8
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;

        default:
            [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];

    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
    }
    else {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
    }

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
    UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //[self setRotatedImage:imageCopy];
    return imageCopy;
}
```

This function is just background to see how I setup the video output...

```
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *videoOut = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
[videoOut setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];
[videoOut setVideoSettings:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey]]; // BGRA is necessary for manual preview
dispatch_queue_t my_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.subsystem.taskXYZ", NULL);
[videoOut setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:my_queue];
if ([self.captureSession canAddOutput:videoOut]) [self.captureSession addOutput:videoOut];
else NSLog(@"Couldn't add video output");
[videoOut release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In setting up the video output, the newly created dispatch queue is not released. You can release it with

```
dispatch_release(queue);
```

But I don't believe this function gets called too often, so the leak probably originates elsewhere. Browsed your code several times, couldn't find any other culprits...

Have you tried searching the leak with the Leaks instrument tool?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. What ended up happening was that the queue was filling up with unprocessed frames, because I wasn't processing fast enough in the delegate object.

My solution was to do (once per processed frame):

```
proctr++;
if ((proctr % 20) == 0) {
  deferImageProcessing = true;
  dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
    [self queueFlushed];
  });
}

- (void)queueFlushed {
  deferImageProcessing = false;
}
```

Then, in the actual image processing code

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
     didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
     fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{ 
  if (deferImageProcessing)
    return;
  // do whatever else I'm doing...
}
```

Essentially, we occasionally suspend image processing until the queue empties.
I hope this is useful.

Comment: Where in your code did you put the proctr++; portion of the code? Did you put it after the //do whatever else I'm doing... section? I'm having the same issue now, crashes after processing about 420 frames.