# How to put watermark on recorded video (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios

i want to put a short video animation (.mov) video over another one recorded with the cam. For example i want to record a video with the iphone cam and when finish i want to automatically put some small movie with alpha transparent background over the recorded one like a watermark and save the result. I know its possible from apps that i've seen .Any help?

Comment: Please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205820/iphone-watermark-on-recorded-video