# Record overlay at the same time AVFoundation iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

I have now fully setup the ability to record video using the `AVFoundation` framework and this is all fine but now I am looking to add an overlay during the record (also visible on the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` Layer)

I can add this overlay `UIView` object to the VideoPreviewLayer but I am struggling how to get the same view to be on the recorded video.This `UIView` could contain anything from `UILabel`s to `UIImageView`s.

Comment: Hmmm good question. I would think that rather than adding a view you'd need to add a layer. Perhaps also these involves some composting of the overlay onto the video input. Will do some thinking...

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the approach, add them into a buffer of some kind (keeping high FPS) where composting of the CALayers can occur. just not sure where to get going.. thanks

Comment: I'm interested in finding an answer to this as its related to something I'm working on. Will update as soon as I make any progress.

Comment: @MightyLeader thanks buddy! - ill let you know if i make any progress

Comment: @MightyLeader did you ever make any progress on this, it's been a while but I now have a requirement to revisit it.

Comment: Why don't you just add your `UIView` as a watermark after the capture is completed? Here's a relevant question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932041/how-can-i-add-a-watermark-in-a-captured-video-on-ios

Comment: @GabrielePetronella No, time and other data needs to be added at the time of recording. Its not water mark. Example is Device Heading at that frame etc.

Comment: Then this answer gives some pointers on how to proceed. You need to extract the frames and write them back to the output buffer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205820/iphone-watermark-on-recorded-video

Comment: @burrows111 I also stuck at the same functionality. Are you able to record video with overlay?

Comment: how to record a dynamic data changes in that view? For example mapView with dot moving in it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the thing you are looking for but i guess you can use Brad Larson's GPU library,there is a class called GPUImageElement which lets you add overlays and views.Please check out the examples,especially the one called Filter showcase and scroll to something called UIElement.

Here is some sample code:

```
 else if (filterType == GPUIMAGE_UIELEMENT)
        {
            GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter *blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
            blendFilter.mix = 1.0;

            NSDate *startTime = [NSDate date];

            UILabel *timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 240.0f, 320.0f)];
            timeLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f];
            timeLabel.text = @"Time: 0.0 s";
            timeLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            timeLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            uiElementInput = [[GPUImageUIElement alloc] initWithView:timeLabel];

            [filter addTarget:blendFilter];
            [uiElementInput addTarget:blendFilter];

            [blendFilter addTarget:filterView];

            __unsafe_unretained GPUImageUIElement *weakUIElementInput = uiElementInput;

            [filter setFrameProcessingCompletionBlock:^(GPUImageOutput * filter, CMTime frameTime){
                timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %f s", -[startTime timeIntervalSinceNow]];
                [weakUIElementInput update];
            }];
        }
```

Comment: OK just hitting on this now, i'll let you know how i get on! Thanks

Comment: Nice find buddy, it's got me on the right path! Thanks for that

Comment: i recording user touch and taps in a view by increasing the value. Is there any possiblity to record that view too?

Comment: how to record dynamic label where text constantly changes?

Answer (score 6):

You want to overlay `UIView`'s, but if you don't mind using `CALayer`s you could
 add your overlay after export using `AVAssetExportSession`'s `AVVideoComposition` property. It has a property, `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool *animationTool` which lets you add animating `CALayer`s to your output, although I think you're out of luck if your overlay's appearance can't be described by `CABasicAnimation`. Your example of a display heading *may* be possible, although I imagine something as simple as a current time counter would not. If you can live with this restriction, the WWDC 2010 code sample 'AVEditDemo' is a good starting point.

If you need more control, you could manually render the overlay `UIView` onto the capture frames, using `[view.layer renderInContext:contextToThenRenderToFrame]` and then write these frames to file using `AVAssetWriter` (once you capture frames to memory you can no longer use `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`).

**Warning**: the frames you are capturing may not arrive at a uniform rate and depend on ambient lighting and even system load. If your overlay changes at a higher rate than the capture video, then you will need to repeat frames in the second solution. This is handled for you by `AVVideoComposition` in the first solution.

P.S. Solution two is fiddly, but without going into details, iOS7 seems to have made this a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

you can find it in AVFoundation Programming Guide in the [editing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_Editing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH8-SW1) part

There is a section that deals with overlay of image. I will try to put up a sample code /project.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out your problem there are two very detailed explanations on the raywenderlich  tutorial site. It is a two part tutorial.

The first one is here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios

The second one is here:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

Good Luck and Hope This Helps!!

Comment: Thanks, these turorials only showcase how to go about it after I have finished recording, I need to do it whilst recording (i.e device heading at that frame)

Comment: Ok. I have found that the Apple Developer Documentation is very helpful. Here is the documentation for AVFoundation:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html  Hope this Helps!