# How can I add a watermark in a captured video on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, avasset

I was wondering if anybody can tell me how I can achieve this. If been thinking of a couple of solutions:

1. Create individual images from the captured video and later merge them per image and after that create a new AVAsset... Sounds a bit complicated don't you think?
2. Merge 2 videos, one is transparent (the one holding the watermark) and the other is the asset captured with the camera.

Answer (score 16):

This code is add a text or string ON the video and after saving video you will play on any player.
Most Advantage of this code is Provide video with sound. And all things in one code(that is text and image).

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

-(void)MixVideoWithText
{
    AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:url options:nil];
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    //If you need audio as well add the Asset Track for audio here

    [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipVideoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
    [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    [compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:[[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] preferredTransform]];

    CGSize sizeOfVideo=[videoAsset naturalSize];

    //TextLayer defines the text they want to add in Video
    //Text of watermark 
    CATextLayer *textOfvideo=[[CATextLayer alloc] init];
    textOfvideo.string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",text];//text is shows the text that you want add in video.
    [textOfvideo setFont:(__bridge CFTypeRef)([UIFont fontWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fontUsed] size:13])];//fontUsed is the name of font
    [textOfvideo setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfVideo.width, sizeOfVideo.height/6)];
    [textOfvideo setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
    [textOfvideo setForegroundColor:[selectedColour CGColor]];

    //Image of watermark 
    UIImage *myImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"];
    CALayer layerCa = [CALayer layer];
    layerCa.contents = (id)myImage.CGImage;
    layerCa.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfVideo.width, sizeOfVideo.height); 
    layerCa.opacity = 1.0; 

    CALayer *optionalLayer=[CALayer layer];
    [optionalL addSublayer:textOfvideo];
    optionalL.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfVideo.width, sizeOfVideo.height);
    [optionalL setMasksToBounds:YES];

    CALayer *parentLayer=[CALayer layer];
    CALayer *videoLayer=[CALayer layer];
    parentLayer.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfVideo.width, sizeOfVideo.height);
    videoLayer.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfVideo.width, sizeOfVideo.height);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
    [parentLayer addSublayer:optionalLayer];
    [parentLayer addSublayer:layerCa];

    AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition=[AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition] ;
    videoComposition.frameDuration=CMTimeMake(1, 30);
    videoComposition.renderSize=sizeOfVideo;
    videoComposition.animationTool=[AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];

    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [mixComposition duration]);
    AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[mixComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
    instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInstruction];
    videoComposition.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: instruction];

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"];
    NSString *destinationPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/utput_%@.mov", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    exportSession.videoComposition=videoComposition;

    exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:destinationPath];
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    switch (exportSession.status)
    {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Export OK");
            if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(destinationPath)) {
                UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(destinationPath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
            }
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
            NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: %@", exportSession.error);
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Export Cancelled");
            break;
    }
  }];
}
```

Shows the error they will come after saving video.

```
-(void) video: (NSString *) videoPath didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo 
{
    if(error)
        NSLog(@"Finished saving video with error: %@", error); 
}
```

Comment: Notice the line above "videoComposition.frameDuration=CMTimeMake(1, 10);" should probably be "videoComposition.frameDuration=CMTimeMake(1, 30);" The default frame rate is 30. Looks better too.

Comment: can you please suggest me how to set proper frame for CATextLayer? see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31780060/how-to-set-catextlayer-in-video-according-to-frame

Comment: This saves the video in the wrong orientation.. Any fix for that?

Comment: use `CGAffineTransform` in `[layerInstruction setTransform: ]` . It will give you exact orientation

Comment: Any suggestions for pixelation on a retina watermark image? Playing with contentsScale and renderScale has not helped. Thanks for your help!

Comment: how to add CGAffineTransform for   portrait mode of video?

Comment: wrong orientation !!!

Comment: Hello its solve my problem but when i play this video it will missing AUDIO. Video play silent.

Comment: @VaibhavSharma it taking too time. suppose I captured 5 minute video it take 2 minute to put watermark on it. any solution ?