# Timestamp as watermark on iOS video

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to add Timestamp watermark on my already recorded and capturing videos in an iOS app.

Here I have got this already posted question and answer on stackoverflow.com

[How can I add a watermark in a captured video on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932041/how-can-i-add-a-watermark-in-a-captured-video-on-ios)

and some other examples on the web.

But it is for still watermark. What I am trying to achieve is

if a user started recording the video on December 20, 2011 at 17:32:24 and the video was 3 minutes long, the timestamp at the beginning of the video would read 12/20/2011 // 17:32:24. The time would change as the video progresses and the timestamp on the last frame of the video would read 12/20/2011 // 17:35:24.

I am confused that how can I get this done? I have tried a lot but not getting through.

Any guidance, highly appreciated.

Thanks