# Overlay Static Text via AVMutableVideoComposition

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition, avmutablevideocomposition

In Swift for iOS, I have an array of `AVURLAsset`. I pass it through a function to stitch/merge the video assets together into one final video. For each video, my goal is to overlay text centered in the frame.

When I play the outputted video, the video assets merge correctly, but I'm unable to understand why none of the text overlays. I tried following an [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684549/add-a-text-overlay-with-avmutablevideocomposition-to-a-specific-timerange), but to no avail. I also tried just overlaying text to a single video following [Ray Wenderlich's tutorial](https://www.kodeco.com/2734-avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos?page=2#toc-anchor-005), but for some reason the same end result :(. Any guidance would be extremely appreciated..

```
func merge(videos: [AVURLAsset], completion: @escaping (_ url: URL, _ asset: AVAssetExportSession)->()) {
let videoComposition = AVMutableComposition()
var lastTime: CMTime = .zero

var maxVideoSize = CGSize.zero

guard let videoCompositionTrack = videoComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)),
      let audioCompositionTrack = videoComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)) else { return }

let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()

let mainParentLayer = CALayer()
let mainVideoLayer = CALayer()
mainParentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: maxVideoSize.width, height: maxVideoSize.height)
mainVideoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: maxVideoSize.width, height: maxVideoSize.height)

mainParentLayer.addSublayer(mainVideoLayer)

var instructions = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction]()
    
print("Main Parent Layer Frame: \(mainParentLayer.frame)")

for video in videos {
    
    if let videoTrack = video.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[safe: 0] {
        videoCompositionTrack.preferredTransform = videoTrack.preferredTransform
        print("Video Track Transform: \(videoTrack.preferredTransform)")

        do {
            try videoCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: video.duration), of: videoTrack, at: lastTime)
            print("Video time range: Start = \(lastTime.seconds), Duration = \(video.duration.seconds) [\(lastTime.seconds + video.duration.seconds > 0 ? "Right" : "Wrong")]")

            if let audioTrack = video.tracks(withMediaType: .audio)[safe: 0] {
                try audioCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: video.duration), of: audioTrack, at: lastTime)
            }

            lastTime = CMTimeAdd(lastTime, video.duration)

            let videoSize = videoTrack.naturalSize.applying(videoTrack.preferredTransform)
            let videoRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: abs(videoSize.width), height: abs(videoSize.height))
            maxVideoSize = CGSize(width: max(maxVideoSize.width, videoRect.width), height: max(maxVideoSize.height, videoRect.height))

            let textLayer = CATextLayer()
            textLayer.string = "TESTING TESTING TESTING"
            textLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            textLayer.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: min(videoRect.height / 10, 100))
            textLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
            textLayer.alignmentMode = .center
            textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
            textLayer.isWrapped = true

            let textHeight: CGFloat = min(videoRect.height / 10, 120)
            let textWidth: CGFloat = videoRect.width
            let xPos = (videoRect.width - textWidth) / 2
            let yPos = (videoRect.height - textHeight) / 2
            textLayer.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: textWidth, height: textHeight)
            textLayer.zPosition = 1
            print("Text Layer Frame: \(textLayer.frame) [\(textLayer.frame.width > 0 && textLayer.frame.height > 0 ? "Right" : "Wrong")]")

            let parentLayer = CALayer()
            parentLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor // Temp background color for debugging
            parentLayer.frame = videoRect
            parentLayer.addSublayer(textLayer)
            
            print("Video Layer zPosition: \(mainVideoLayer.zPosition), Text Layer zPosition: \(textLayer.zPosition) [\(textLayer.zPosition > mainVideoLayer.zPosition ? "Right" : "Wrong")]")

            let videoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
            videoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: lastTime - video.duration, duration: video.duration)
            let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
            videoCompositionInstruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
            instructions.append(videoCompositionInstruction)

            parentLayer.zPosition = 0
            mainParentLayer.addSublayer(parentLayer)
            
            print("Parent Layer Frame: \(parentLayer.frame), Background Color: \(parentLayer.backgroundColor.debugDescription)")
            print("Text Layer Frame: \(textLayer.frame)")
            
        } catch {
            print("Failed to insert track: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    }
}

mainParentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: maxVideoSize.width, height: maxVideoSize.height)
mainVideoLayer.frame = mainParentLayer.frame

mainComposition.renderSize = maxVideoSize
mainComposition.instructions = instructions
mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 30)
mainComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: mainVideoLayer, in: mainParentLayer)

print("Final Main Parent Layer Frame: \(mainParentLayer.frame)")
print("Number of Sublayers in Main Parent Layer: \(mainParentLayer.sublayers?.count ?? 0)")

let outputUrl = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + "merged" + ".mp4")

print("Pre-Export Main Parent Layer Frame: \(mainParentLayer.frame)")
print("Pre-Export Number of Sublayers in Main Parent Layer: \(mainParentLayer.sublayers?.count ?? 0)")
if let sublayers = mainParentLayer.sublayers {
    for (index, layer) in sublayers.enumerated() {
        print("Layer \(index): \(layer), Frame: \(layer.frame), zPosition: \(layer.zPosition)")
    }
}

guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: videoComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else { return }

exporter.videoComposition = mainComposition
exporter.outputURL = outputUrl
exporter.outputFileType = .mp4
exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

if let videoComposition = exporter.videoComposition {
    print("Export Video Composition Render Size: \(videoComposition.renderSize)")
    print("Export Video Composition Frame Duration: \(videoComposition.frameDuration)")
    print("Export Video Composition Instructions Count: \(videoComposition.instructions.count)")
}

exporter.exportAsynchronously {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let outputUrl = exporter.outputURL, exporter.status == .completed {
            completion(outputUrl, exporter)
        } else if let error = exporter.error {
            print("Export failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
play(video: exporter.asset)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, each video segment is associated with a separate parent layer containing both the video and text layers. But the [`AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avvideocompositioncoreanimationtool) is not correctly configured to composite these layers over the video.

You should create a single main video layer (`mainVideoLayer`) and add it to a main parent layer (`mainParentLayer`). Then, add each video's text layer to the `mainParentLayer`. This ensures a proper hierarchy where the text overlays are correctly positioned over the video content.
And configure the `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` with the `mainVideoLayer` as the video layer to process and the `mainParentLayer` as the animation layer.

Make sure that each [`AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmutablevideocompositioninstruction/) correctly spans the entire duration of its corresponding video segment. That should be important for seamless playback and proper overlay of text.

Your `merge` function would be (relevant extracts only):

```swift
func merge(videos: [AVURLAsset], completion: @escaping (_ url: URL, _ asset: AVAssetExportSession)->()) {
    // initial setup code remains the same

    // Create a main parent layer that will host all individual video layers
    let mainParentLayer = CALayer()
    mainParentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: maxVideoSize.width, height: maxVideoSize.height)
    
    let mainVideoLayer = CALayer()
    mainVideoLayer.frame = mainParentLayer.frame
    mainParentLayer.addSublayer(mainVideoLayer)

    // Add each video layer and its corresponding text layer
    for video in videos {
        // video processing code remains the same

        // Add the video layer and text layer to the main parent layer
        mainParentLayer.addSublayer(parentLayer)
    }

    // Set up the main composition
    mainComposition.renderSize = maxVideoSize
    mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 30) // Assuming 30 fps
    mainComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: mainVideoLayer, in: mainParentLayer)

    // export setup code remains the same
}
```

---

> I  tried following and updating the relevant extracts of code, but the text overlay still doesn't appear in each/any video segment...the merged video remains to play correctly otherwise.
> I edited my post with the latest function for reference.

The size and position of the `mainParentLayer` and `mainVideoLayer` are set based on `maxVideoSize`, which is initially zero and updated within the loop. Make sure the frame of `mainParentLayer` is updated after determining the maximum video size.
The time range for each `videoCompositionInstruction` is set incorrectly. It should start from the beginning of the last time, not from the last time itself.
You are adding each video's `parentLayer` to `mainParentLayer` within the loop. That might be causing an overlap issue or an incorrect layer hierarchy. The order in which layers are added and properties are set is important. Make sure all layer properties are correctly set before they are added to their parent layers.

The preferred transform of the video track is set for each video, but it is important to check if this is properly applied to the video layer within the composition.

Considering all of the above, the updated code might look like this:

```swift
func merge(videos: [AVURLAsset], completion: @escaping (_ url: URL, _ asset: AVAssetExportSession)->()) {
    // initial setup code remains the same

    var instructions = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction]()
    
    for video in videos {
        // video track processing code remains the same

        // Update maxVideoSize calculation here, if necessary

        // Text layer setup remains the same

        let parentLayer = CALayer()
        parentLayer.frame = videoRect
        parentLayer.addSublayer(textLayer)

        let videoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
        videoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: lastTime - video.duration, duration: video.duration)
        let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
        videoCompositionInstruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
        instructions.append(videoCompositionInstruction)

        mainParentLayer.addSublayer(parentLayer)
        // rest of the loop remains the same
    }

    // Update the frame of mainParentLayer after the loop
    mainParentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: maxVideoSize.width, height: maxVideoSize.height)
    mainVideoLayer.frame = mainParentLayer.frame

    mainComposition.instructions = instructions
    mainComposition.renderSize = maxVideoSize
    // rest of the function remains the same
}
```

---

> i updated my code based on your latest and still am unable to see text for each/any video segment, while the videos themselves correctly play. :(

Make sure the text layers are not being obscured by other layers. That can be checked by setting different background colors for each layer temporarily. And confirm that the `zPosition` of the text layers is higher than the video layers.

The properties of `CATextLayer` such as `fontSize` and `frame` must be correctly set to make sure the text is visible and within the bounds of the video frame. Check if the font size is appropriate for the video size. A very large font size might cause the text to appear off-screen.

Review the `timeRange` set for each `videoCompositionInstruction`. It should correctly span the duration of each video segment.
Verify that the `preferredTransform` of each video track is correctly applied. An incorrect transform can lead to unexpected layer positioning.
Make sure `mainComposition.renderSize` and `mainComposition.frameDuration` are set appropriately. If these are incorrect, it could affect the visibility and placement of the text layers.

Debugging steps could include adding print statements to log the frame and other properties of the text layers to make sure they are being set as expected.
Try and temporarily simplify the composition to include just one video and its text layer. That can help isolate whether the issue is with individual layers or the composition of multiple layers.
Use a visual debugging tool or set distinct background colors for each layer to visually inspect the layer hierarchy and positioning.
Make sure the settings for [`AVAssetExportSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetexportsession) are correct and support the video format and composition.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i tried following and updating the relevant extracts of code, but the text overlay still doesn't appear in each/any video segment...the merged video remains to play correctly otherwise. i edited my post with the latest function for reference!

Comment: thanks for the additional info. i'm not sure if i'm mistakenly overlooking something, but i updated my code based on your latest and still am unable to see text for each/any video segment, while the videos themselves correctly play. :( i edited my post with the latest function based on your latest answer!

Comment: @Chris Not sure. I have edited the answer with some additional suggestions.

Comment: yeah...i updated my post with a bunch of print statements to pin down what's wrong and everything seems to be in order yet the textLayer and even the parent layer with a green background color don't appear despite the videos still playing correctly. admittedly am lost. were you by chance able to produce a working code sample on your end based on the answers you had provided?

Comment: @Chris I wonder if the `mainVideoLayer` is inadvertently obscuring the text and colored layers. Since `mainVideoLayer` is added first to `mainParentLayer`, it might be covering the other layers.

Comment: I checked the zPositions of all the sublayers and the orders seem to be correct... :(. any other thoughts by chance or were you able to produce a working code sample by chance? i tried following ray wenderlich's tutorial for even 1 video/1 text overlay and ended up with the same result... https://www.kodeco.com/2734-avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos?page=2#toc-anchor-005

Comment: @Chris No, nothing on my side. That doesn't seem to be easily supported.

Comment: @Chris see if you can add each layer within video within a loop to check if that is working or not. At this point, I think the problem need to be list of subproblemed to see which line of code are impacting this process. I worked with AVFoundation sometime ago and it wasn't clear cut documentation/code itself as well.

Comment: @Meep the videos merge and play correctly. the text layer is the only one that doesn't display on the playback despite appearing in the right order as a sublayer. not sure if you might've gotten a different result using my code or have a working code sample to test? i'm admittedly so lost at this point.

Comment: @Chris No working code yet. You could try and create a simple UIView and add a CATextLayer with the same properties as in your video composition process. This will confirm if the CATextLayer setup is correct outside the context of video processing. Try also to remove the CATextLayer from the composition and instead add a colored CALayer above the mainVideoLayer to see if it's visible in the final composition.  Use an AVPlayerLayer to directly play the composition before exporting, just to identify if the export process is affecting the visibility of the text layer.

Comment: @Chris my app works with the CMSampleBuffer and adding the text on the video real time. There are series of conversions of the types of the ciimage to pixelbuffer. I don't think I did your approach before. What about if you can create a video only with text layer then add a green background?