# How to add a watermark to video (simple way)?

Tags: ios, xcode, video, watermark

What is the simplest way to add a watermark to a video in iOS?

This is my code do far:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://scontent-a.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t50.2886-16/10619021_616434485141882_380154097_n.mp4"];
videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[videoPlayer.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[videoPlayer.moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20add%20watermark%20on%20video%20ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of, if a watermark during play is what you want, is to superinpose a semitransparent image to your  video player.

- create a UIImageView
- make sure the UIImageView has the same size and layout constraints of your video
- make sure that the UIImageView is semitransparent (not opaque and with an appropriate alpha, if required)
- [MPMoviePlayerViewController addSubview:]

and you should be about done.

Hope it helps

**EDIT** and there is the *correct* way to do it:

[Add watermark on Video [SO answer]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932041/how-can-i-add-a-watermark-in-a-captured-video-on-ios)

as pointed out by sanjeet in it's comment.