# Xamarin.iOS - ExportAsynchronously fails

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, watermark, video-watermarking

Firstly I should mention I'm new a this (iOS and Xamarin).
I'm trying to watermark a video using a image and a text.

I've ported most of the code from the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22016800/5275669.

The entire code is pasted here:

```
try {

            var videoAsset = AVUrlAsset.FromUrl (new NSUrl (filepath, false)) as AVUrlAsset;
            AVMutableComposition mixComposition = AVMutableComposition.Create ();
            var compositionVideoTracks = mixComposition.AddMutableTrack (AVMediaType.Video, 0);
            AVAssetTrack clipVideoTrack = videoAsset.TracksWithMediaType (AVMediaType.Video) [0];
            var compositionAudioTrack = mixComposition.AddMutableTrack (AVMediaType.Audio, 0);
            AVAssetTrack clipAudioTrack = videoAsset.TracksWithMediaType (AVMediaType.Audio) [0];

            NSError error;
            CMTimeRange timeRangeInAsset = new CMTimeRange ();
            timeRangeInAsset.Start = CMTime.Zero;
            timeRangeInAsset.Duration = videoAsset.Duration;
            compositionVideoTracks.InsertTimeRange (timeRangeInAsset, clipVideoTrack, CMTime.Zero, out error);
            compositionVideoTracks.InsertTimeRange (timeRangeInAsset, clipAudioTrack, CMTime.Zero, out error);
            compositionVideoTracks.PreferredTransform = clipVideoTrack.PreferredTransform;

            CGSize sizeOfVideo = videoAsset.NaturalSize;

            CATextLayer textOfvideo = (CATextLayer)CATextLayer.Create ();
            textOfvideo.String = String.Format ("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString (), "Test app");
            textOfvideo.SetFont (CGFont.CreateWithFontName ("Helvetica"));
            textOfvideo.FontSize = 50;
            textOfvideo.AlignmentMode = CATextLayer.AlignmentCenter;
            textOfvideo.Frame = new CGRect (0, 0, sizeOfVideo.Width, sizeOfVideo.Height / 6);
            textOfvideo.ForegroundColor = new CGColor (255, 0, 0);

            UIImage myImage = UIImage.FromFile ("Icon-Small.png");
            CALayer layerCa = CALayer.Create ();
            layerCa.Contents = myImage.CGImage;
            layerCa.Frame = new CGRect (0, 0, 100, 100);
            layerCa.Opacity = 0.65F;

            CALayer optionalLayer = CALayer.Create ();
            optionalLayer.AddSublayer (textOfvideo);
            optionalLayer.Frame = new CGRect (0, 0, sizeOfVideo.Width, sizeOfVideo.Height);
            optionalLayer.MasksToBounds = true;

            CALayer parentLayer = CALayer.Create ();
            CALayer videoLayer = CALayer.Create ();
            parentLayer.Frame = new CGRect (0, 0, sizeOfVideo.Width, sizeOfVideo.Height);
            videoLayer.Frame = new CGRect (0, 0, sizeOfVideo.Width, sizeOfVideo.Height);
            parentLayer.AddSublayer (videoLayer);
            parentLayer.AddSublayer (layerCa);
            parentLayer.AddSublayer (textOfvideo);

            AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition.Create ();
            videoComposition.RenderSize = sizeOfVideo;
            videoComposition.FrameDuration = new CMTime (1, 30);
            videoComposition.AnimationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool.FromLayer (videoLayer, parentLayer);

            AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction.Create () as AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction;
            CMTimeRange timeRangeInstruction = new CMTimeRange ();
            timeRangeInstruction.Start = CMTime.Zero;
            timeRangeInstruction.Duration = mixComposition.Duration;
            instruction.TimeRange = timeRangeInstruction;
            AVAssetTrack videoTrack = mixComposition.TracksWithMediaType (AVMediaType.Video) [0];

            AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction.FromAssetTrack (videoTrack);
            instruction.LayerInstructions = new AVVideoCompositionLayerInstruction[] { layerInstruction };
            List<AVVideoCompositionInstruction> instructions = new List<AVVideoCompositionInstruction> ();
            instructions.Add (instruction);
            videoComposition.Instructions = instructions.ToArray ();

            var exportSession = new AVAssetExportSession (mixComposition, AVAssetExportSession.PresetMediumQuality);
            exportSession.VideoComposition = videoComposition;

            Console.WriteLine ("Original path is {0}", filepath);
            string newFileName = Path.GetFileName (filepath);
            newFileName = newFileName.Replace (".mp4", "_wm.mp4");
            string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName (filepath);
            string videoOutFilePath = Path.Combine (directoryName, newFileName);
            Console.WriteLine ("New path is {0}", videoOutFilePath);

            exportSession.OutputFileType = AVFileType.Mpeg4;
            exportSession.OutputUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename (videoOutFilePath);
            exportSession.ShouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true;
            exportSession.ExportAsynchronously (() => {
                AVAssetExportSessionStatus status = exportSession.Status;
                Console.WriteLine ("Done with handler. Status: " + status.ToString ());
                switch (status) {
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed:
                    Console.WriteLine ("Sucessfully Completed");
                    if (File.Exists (videoOutFilePath)) {
                        Console.WriteLine ("Created!!");
                    } else
                        Console.WriteLine ("Failed");
                    break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
                    break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Exporting:
                    break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:
                    Console.WriteLine ("Task failed => {0}", exportSession.Error);
                    Console.WriteLine (exportSession.Error.Description);
                    break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Unknown:
                    break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Waiting:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            });

            if (File.Exists (videoOutFilePath))
                return videoOutFilePath;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Error occured : {0}", ex.Message);
        }
```

I keep getting the following error:
Task failed => Cannot Complete Export
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11820 "Cannot Complete Export" UserInfo=0x18896070 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try exporting again., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Export}

If I replace this

```
var exportSession = new AVAssetExportSession (mixComposition, AVAssetExportSession.PresetMediumQuality);
```

with

```
var exportSession = new AVAssetExportSession (videoAsset, AVAssetExportSession.PresetMediumQuality);
```

it works fine but with no watermark

Can anyone help with this??

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to solve this issue by changing these lines

```
compositionVideoTracks.InsertTimeRange (timeRangeInAsset, clipVideoTrack, CMTime.Zero, out error);
compositionVideoTracks.InsertTimeRange (timeRangeInAsset, clipAudioTrack, CMTime.Zero, out error);
compositionVideoTracks.PreferredTransform = clipVideoTrack.PreferredTransform;
```

to this:

```
compositionVideoTracks.InsertTimeRange (timeRangeInAsset, clipVideoTrack, CMTime.Zero, out error);
compositionAudioTrack.InsertTimeRange (timeRangeInAsset, clipAudioTrack, CMTime.Zero, out error);
compositionVideoTracks.PreferredTransform = clipVideoTrack.PreferredTransform;
```

Although I'm not sure why this worked. Could any one explain this?