# I have a .mp4 video how i can add water mark

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I have .mp4 video and i want to generate new video from that with watermarked on proper place.

Is there possibilities where i can create function and pass video it will return me Water marked video.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

This code is add a text or string ON the video and after saving video you will play on any player.
Most Advantage of this code is Provide video with sound. And all things in one code(that is text and image).

```
    #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

    -(void)MixVideoWithText
    {
        AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:url options:nil];
        AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

        AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
        AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
        AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
        AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
        //If you need audio as well add the Asset Track for audio here

        [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipVideoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
        [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

        [compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:[[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] preferredTransform]];

        CGSize sizeOfVideo=[videoAsset naturalSize];

        //TextLayer defines the text they want to add in Video
        //Text of watermark 
        CATextLayer *textOfvideo=[[CATextLayer alloc] init];
        textOfvideo.string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",text];//text is shows the text that you want add in video.
        [textOfvideo setFont:(__bridge CFTypeRef)([UIFont fontWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fontUsed] size:13])];//fontUsed is the name of font
        [textOfvideo setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfVideo.width, sizeOfVideo.height/6)];
        [textOfvideo setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
        [textOfvideo setForegroundColor:[selectedColour CGColor]];

        //Image of watermark 
        UIImage *myImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"];
        CALayer layerCa = [CALayer layer];
        layerCa.contents = (id)myImage.CGImage;
        layerCa.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfVideo.width, sizeOfVideo.height); 
        layerCa.opacity = 1.0; 

        CALayer *optionalLayer=[CALayer layer];
        [optionalL addSublayer:textOfvideo];
        optionalL.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfVideo.width, sizeOfVideo.height);
        [optionalL setMasksToBounds:YES];

        CALayer *parentLayer=[CALayer layer];
        CALayer *videoLayer=[CALayer layer];
        parentLayer.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfVideo.width, sizeOfVideo.height);
        videoLayer.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfVideo.width, sizeOfVideo.height);
        [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
        [parentLayer addSublayer:optionalLayer];
        [parentLayer addSublayer:layerCa];

        AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition=[AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition] ;
        videoComposition.frameDuration=CMTimeMake(1, 30);
        videoComposition.renderSize=sizeOfVideo;
        videoComposition.animationTool=[AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];

        AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
        instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [mixComposition duration]);
        AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[mixComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
        AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
        instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInstruction];
        videoComposition.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: instruction];

        NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"];
        NSString *destinationPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/utput_%@.mov", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

        AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
        exportSession.videoComposition=videoComposition;

        exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:destinationPath];
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
        [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        switch (exportSession.status)
        {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                NSLog(@"Export OK");
                if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(destinationPath)) {
                    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(destinationPath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
                }
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                NSLog (@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed: %@", exportSession.error);
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                NSLog(@"Export Cancelled");
                break;
        }
      }];
    }
Shows the error they will come after saving video.

    -(void) video: (NSString *) videoPath didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo 
    {
        if(error)
            NSLog(@"Finished saving video with error: %@", error); 
    }
```

From :https://stackoverflow.com/a/22016800/3901620