# Adding watermark to currently recording video and save with watermark

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I  would like to know if there is any way to add a watermark to a video which is currently recording and save it with the watermark. (I know about adding watermarks to video files that are already available in app bundle and exporting it with watermark).

[iPhone Watermark on recorded Video.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205820/iphone-watermark-on-recorded-video)

I checked this link. Accepted answer is not good one. The most voted answer is applicable only if there is already a video file in your bundle. (Please read the answer before suggesting that.)

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Watermark on recorded Video.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205820/iphone-watermark-on-recorded-video)

Comment: That answer is not a good one because it wont work for long time recording. Saving every frame as an image in memory and combine it for video will be more costly.

Comment: So, you can do trick, just dislpay overlay when recording , and after saving use http://stackoverflow.com/a/8797944/1597744 this .

Comment: Yea but It required to load the entire video again and need to export it. means it need the effort of recording and saving of two video. If there is no other option then only its possible. I think you got what I meant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this purpose its better to use `GPUImage` library (An open source library available in Git hub), It contains so many filter and its possible add overlay using `GPUImageOverlayBlendFilter`. That contains sample `FilterShowCase` that explains lot about using the filters. It uses GPU  so that it takes the overhead of processing the image. The full credits goes to @Brad Larson the one who created such a great library.