# iOS Add a image in to Video for only certain duration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6.1, video-editing

I want to add a image in to video only some milliseconds, so i Have try to do this with **CALayer**,

```
UIImage *animationImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
CALayer *overlayLayer1 = [CALayer layer];
[overlayLayer1 setContents:(id)[animationImage CGImage]];
//overlayLayer1.frame = CGRectMake(size.width/2-64, size.height/2 + 200, 128, 128);

overlayLayer1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
[overlayLayer1 setMasksToBounds:YES];


CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
[parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];


[parentLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer1];
```

It works and i Can possible to make an Output video but in the output video shows arrow png image whole duration but i want to add that only 2 seconds.

is possible to make this?

Comment: have a look at @julio Bailon's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205820/iphone-watermark-on-recorded-video#7205820

Answer (score 1):

Another way it use AVAssetWriter to generate video from image and then use AVMutableVideoComposition for combine assets.
you can adjust the duration of asset:

```
[compositionVideoTracks insertTimeRange:timeRange ofTrack:videoTrack atTime:_currentDuration error:&error];
```

Comment: It will fail in case the images are transparent then the video made with the images will have BLACK background :D

Answer (score 0):

Its work for me for text layer

```
- (void)applyVideoEffectsToComposition:(AVMutableVideoComposition *)composition size:(CGSize)size{
// 1 - Set up the text layer
CATextLayer *subtitle1Text = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
[subtitle1Text setFont:@"Helvetica-Bold"];
[subtitle1Text setFontSize:36];
[subtitle1Text setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, 100)];
[subtitle1Text setString:_subTitle1.text];
[subtitle1Text setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
[subtitle1Text setForegroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];

// 2 - The usual overlay
CALayer *overlayLayer = [CALayer layer];
[overlayLayer addSublayer:subtitle1Text];
overlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
[overlayLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

// the code for the opacity animation which then removes the text
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
[animation setDuration:2]; //duration
[animation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
[animation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
[animation setBeginTime:5]; // time to show text
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
[subtitle1Text addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
////

CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
[parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer];

composition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool
                             videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];}
```

Comment: Correct way @Hardik.
Can you suggest what if i have 2400 images and want to put images as 24F/sec over a video ?

Answer (score -1):

After 2 second you have to remove `overLayer1` from `parentLayer`.

```
[overLayer1 removeFromSuperlayer];
```

Comment: where i write the code '[overLayer1 removeFromSuperlayer];' . and how to identify that 2 seconds? will you please explain brief?

Comment: after adding sublayer.. call one method using performselector with delay 2 second.On inside that method u can call the above

Comment: totally wrong you can't use this approach with the AVMutableVideoComposition

Comment: @PurushottamSain : you got solution ?