# Watermark (overlap) a video with an image on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, video-watermarking

I try in vain to watermark an existing video with the AVFoundation library. I followed the instructions and tried to rewrite the code in Swift from the third answer in this question: [iPhone Watermark on recorded Video.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205820/iphone-watermark-on-recorded-video) – but this doesn't work for me.

Every time when run my code I only see a black video rendered with the length of my source video which needs to be watermarked. My goal is to fade in the watermark after 5 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
let composition = AVMutableComposition()
let vidAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: moviePath), options: nil)

// GET THE VIDEO TRACK
let vtrack =  vidAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
let videoTrack:AVAssetTrack = vtrack[0]
let vid_timerange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, vidAsset.duration)

do {
    let compositionvideoTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
    try compositionvideoTrack.insertTimeRange(vid_timerange, ofTrack: videoTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)

    compositionvideoTrack.preferredTransform = videoTrack.preferredTransform
} catch {
    print(error)
}

let animationImage: UIImage = self.artworkImage

let artWorkOverlayLayer: CALayer = CALayer()
artWorkOverlayLayer.contents = (animationImage.CGImage as! AnyObject)
artWorkOverlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 512, 512)
artWorkOverlayLayer.opacity = 0
artWorkOverlayLayer.masksToBounds = true

let animation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
animation.duration = 10
animation.repeatCount = 0
animation.autoreverses = false
animation.fromValue = Int(0.0)
animation.toValue = Int(1.0)
animation.beginTime = 5.0
artWorkOverlayLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "animateOpacity")

let videolayer = CALayer()
videolayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoTrack.naturalSize.width, videoTrack.naturalSize.height)

let parentlayer = CALayer()
parentlayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoTrack.naturalSize.width, videoTrack.naturalSize.height)
parentlayer.addSublayer(artWorkOverlayLayer)

let layercomposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
layercomposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
layercomposition.renderSize = videoTrack.naturalSize
layercomposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videolayer, inLayer: parentlayer)

let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, composition.duration)
let videotrack = composition.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as AVAssetTrack
let layerinstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videotrack)
instruction.layerInstructions = NSArray(object: layerinstruction) as! [AVVideoCompositionLayerInstruction]
layercomposition.instructions = NSArray(object: instruction) as! [AVVideoCompositionInstructionProtocol]

// EXPORT
let filePath: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingString("output-tmp.mp4"))

let assetExportSession: AVAssetExportSession! = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)

assetExportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
assetExportSession.outputURL = filePath
assetExportSession.videoComposition = layercomposition

assetExportSession.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({() -> Void in
    print(filePath)
})
```

Comment: Try add overlay as subview to `videoTrack` directly? While testing, better to comment out all animation code.

Comment: can you give me an example? I don't really know what you mean with adding overlay as subview to videoTrack? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I should say try add to `videolayer` directly, rather then creating a parent view. Also, did you confirm that in your current implementation, if you didn't add the overlay separately, will the video work as expected?

Comment: I am sorry... I am completely new in this and I don't know how to add it to video layer directly?

Comment: Forget about his first. What happens, 1. when you not adding any animation? 2. Not adding `artWorkOverlayLayer`. As I didn't see anyplace you add video layer as a sublayer of parentlayer