# How to add a overlay text on captured video/image in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to add a overlay text like "Company watermark" on captured video or image programatically in swift. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205820/iphone-watermark-on-recorded-video) for video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// create text Layer

```
let titleLayer = CATextLayer()
titleLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
titleLayer.string = "Company watermark"
titleLayer.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 28)
titleLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
titleLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
titleLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, size.width, size.height / 6)
yourView.layer.addSublayer(titleLayer)
```

Hope it will help you for adding text in video.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: how to fix pixelated text ?