# How to add Date & time on offline(recorded) video in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

I would like to embed a date & Time on a video as it records, then save it in the Camera Roll. When this video is played on any other device this text should show.

Comment: You want to add date & time as watermark on Video ?

Comment: yes i want to add date & time as watermark. i try many code but not perfect solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone Watermark on recorded Video.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205820/iphone-watermark-on-recorded-video)

Comment: Now added date & time as watermark on Video but how to set current second show on video