# AVFoundation -> record camera video with animated overlay

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, ios-camera

In my app I am recording camera output with AVFoundation. I am trying to save not just camera output, but also GUI layout(overlay) presented over camera surface.

I am executing some basic animations on GUI layer( showing and hiding of UIView and UIProgressView animation).

[image]

So is it somehow possible to record camera output with animated overlay?

My research:

1.) https://www.raywenderlich.com/2734-avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

Post processing is not an option. And this solution would not work for my problem.

2.) [iPhone Watermark on recorded Video.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205820/iphone-watermark-on-recorded-video)
So it is possible to add watermark. Maybe it would be possible to capture frame from camera, capture frame from overlay then overlaying the captured camera frame with the captured overlay frame? :(

Answer (score 0):

My solution (i am working on it right now) is create an object that subclass a CALayer and add it to your preview uiview.layer.

```
protocol VideoCameraLayer {
  func playAnimation()
  func stopAnimation()
}

class CircleFaceLayer: : CALayer,VideoCameraLayer{
  init(){
   //... add sublayers to this layer or whatever you need 
  }

  func playAnimation(){
  //Add animation/s to your layer/sublayers
  }

  func stopAnimation(){
  //Pause animation/s to your layer/sublayers
  }
}
```

You could use this object and sublayering in your avassetexportsession.animatioToll and in your preview layer in your UIView:

```
 let animatedLayer:VideoCameraLayer = CircleFaceLayer()
 self.view.layer.addSublayer(animatedLayer)
```